# Miniconda installation error on aarch64 system

Tags: python, arm64, miniconda

I am tyring to install `miniconda` on my `aarch64` GNU/Linux embedded platform. Following below steps:

1. Download file from `wget http://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-py39_23.5.2-0-Linux-aarch64.sh`
2. Trying to install: `sudo /bin/sh Miniconda3-py39_23.5.2-0-Linux-aarch64.sh`. Accept the Licenses and specifying desired location. Then I get

   ```
   Unpacking payload ...
   Illegal instruction
   ```

I am not sure what is causing this. How can I install it correctly?

Thanks in advance.

P.S: please let me know if any info is missng.